# ember-app blank after upgrade to 2.12

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-2

I'm trying to get an app from Ember 1.13 to Ember 2.12.

I upgraded ember-cli and all of that. I did the steps in [this guide](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases), most importantly

```
ember init
```

and then resolved the differences that appeared.

The result is that I have a blank page. Most resources are loaded. `application.hbs` contains "Hello World", but this does not show. The router has a root route defined.

When I navigate to the root, Chrome downloads the usual JS files

The new `index.html` seems to require `www.js`, and `www.css`, but these were not generated with `ember init`. Searching the web for "ember www.js" did not yield anything useful.

Right now, I'm in a state with:

- Blank page
- No errors, warnings or deprecations in the Chrome Web Developer Console
- Ember inspector does not detect the Ember app.

Probably I've missed something during the "ember init" step, but it's hard to know what exactly.

How would I debug this when there are no error messages? Simply start over?

Answer (score 1):

That upgrade is a big jump. I encourage you to follow the below migration path,

1.13 -> 2.0 -> 2.4 -> 2.8 -> 2.10 -> 2.12

Go through deprecations guide https://emberjs.com/deprecations/v2.x/ and if your app is using the deprecated methods in your app, then update to that particular version and proceed further.

In every upgrade just ensure you need to fix deprecation, upgrade the corresponding ember-cli and follow upgrade path carefully.

For ember-cli upgrade, In the below URL you can replace from and to ember-cli version to get the exact updated changes

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output/compare/v1.13.0...v2.12.0